# SQL display function

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I am new to SQL and wanted to ask if anyone could please help me with a query.

I want to sum transactions by transaction date for all transactions in a table.

this query

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM transactions 
GROUP BY transaction_date
```

sums the transactions for each date but gives me numbers instead of the actual dates?

i.e.:

```
1  - 40,
2  - 165,
3  - 50
```

Instead of 1, 2, 3, etc. how would I display the actual date that the transaction took place.

i.e.

```
2014-01-23 - 40, 
2014-01-24 - 165,
2014-01-25 - 50
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select it too:

```
SELECT transaction_date, SUM(amount) FROM transactions GROUP BY transaction_date
```